# Dockerfile内で同一ファイルを同じ場所に複数回COPYしたとき、イメージサイズが大きくなるのはなぜか

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Dockerfile内で同一ファイルを同じ場所に複数回COPYしたとき、docker buildで生成したコンテナに含まれるファイルは1つしかないのにも関わらず、コンテナのイメージサイズが1回コピーした場合よりも大きくなるのはなぜでしょうか？

下記のようなDockerfileの場合です。

```
FROM python:3.9.13

WORKDIR /app

COPY . /app
COPY . /app
```

カレントディレクトリには`test.txt`はDockerfileの他に数MBのテキストファイルがあります。

```bash
~/test$ ls
Dockerfile  test.txt
```

`docker build`は下記で実施しています。

```bash
~/test$ docker build -t test .
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jhashimotoさんの回答では「コンテナのイメージサイズが1回コピーした場合よりも大きくなるのはなぜでしょうか？」には答えられていないので、もう少し補足します。

[Dockerfile 記述のベストプラクティス](https://matsuand.github.io/docs.docker.jp.onthefly/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/)

> 各コマンドからは 1 つずつレイヤーが生成されます。
> （略）
> イメージを実行してコンテナーが生成されると、それまであったレイヤーの上に **書き込み可能なレイヤー**（「コンテナーレイヤー」）が加えられます。 実行されているコンテナーへの変更、つまり新規ファイル生成や既存ファイル編集、ファイル削除などはすべて、この書き込みレイヤーに書き込まれます。

つまり、下のレイヤーがどうであれ、`COPY`で行われた書き込みは全て新しいレイヤー上に表現されます。
差分検出してくれれば…という期待はわからなくもないですが、そうなっていません。これは通常の`cp`コマンドなどでも同じで、上書き可能かどうかの判断は行われますが、コピー元・コピー先の内容比較は行わずに常に上書きされます。

Answer (score 1):

COPYコマンドの度にレイヤーが生成されるから、ではないでしょうか。

[Dockerfile 記述のベストプラクティス | Docker ドキュメント](https://matsuand.github.io/docs.docker.jp.onthefly/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/)

> 各コマンドからは 1 つずつレイヤーが生成されます。

[caching - Docker have the same file in multiple layers - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70695421/docker-have-the-same-file-in-multiple-layers)

本家に同様のQAがありました。